# Compute the weighted average in PyTorch

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, tensor

Assuming we have a tensor A, with shape

```
CxH
```

And tensor W, representing the weights, with shape `H`

Tensor A represents some features with dim `C` for each spatial location in `H` (flattened), and weights `W` represents the weight for each spatial location. Instead of computing the mean via:

```
torch.mul(A, W).mean(1)
```

How can we compute the weighted average ?
The output dim should be of size `C`.

Would it be:

```
Z = torch.mul(A, W)
Weighted_average = torch.sum(Z, dim=1) / torch.sum(W)
```

Answer (score 0):

> weights W represents the weight for each spatial location

This implies you should multiply each one of the `H` locations in `A` with its corresponding weight from `W`. A matrix multiplication does the summation: `A@W`, then you can normalize with the total sum of the weights vector: `W.sum()`.

So your question seems correct: `w_mean = A@W / W.sum()`.

Also, you could compute the average feature instead of normalizing, this would indeed correspond to `(A*W).mean(1)`, where we retain dimensionality with `*` (*vs.* `@` which would reduce it), only to average on `axis=1` afterward.

<sub>Note `@` and `*` correspond to `torch.matmul` and `torch.mul`, respectively.</sub>